# Finding an orthonormal eigenbasis of an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Define an inner product on the $\Bbb R$-vector space $\Bbb R[x]_\le2$ by $<f,g>=\int_{-1}^1 f(t)g(t) dt$. Consider $J \in End (\Bbb R[x]_\le2)$ defined by $(Jf)(x)=1/8 \int_{-1}^1 (7+6(x+t)-6xt-15(x^2+t^2)+45x^2t^2)f(t) dt$

It is known that $J$ is self-adjoint.

Find an orthonormal eigenbasis for $J$.

I know that i need to find the eigenvectors of $J$ and then since J is  self-adjoint they are normal and therefore the eigenvectors will be orthongonal. From there i know i just have to normalize the eigenvectors. My issue is finding the eigenvectors themselves which i dont know how to do.

Comment: I think you should translate everything to $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: what would this help with?

Comment: Erm... Finding eigenvectors and eigenvalues...

Comment: so i realized the eigenvalues for $J$ are 1 and -1, how do i use this information to find the eigenvectors

Comment: How did you realize that?

Comment: essentially by doing what you said hahah.. your small comment allowed me to solve this whole problem, thanks! That small push in the right direction really helped.

Comment: This is what I like. :o)